# How can I improve the specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am learning ruby on rails. And in my new project I am using rspec, shoulda matchers. I just want to know how can I improve the way of writing specs. And I need to reuse "Term" in other model specs also. How can I do that?

Thanks

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Portfolio, type: :model do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:code) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }

  it "has a valid factory" do
      expect(FactoryGirl.create(:portfolio)).to be_valid
  end  

  it { should belong_to(:client) }
  it { should belong_to(:custodian) }

  let(:client) { FactoryGirl.create(:client) }
  let(:bank) { FactoryGirl.create(:bank)  }
  let(:product_cash) { ProductType.create(code: "CASH", name: "Cash") }
  let(:product_interest) { ProductType.create(code: "INTEREST", name: "Interest Bearing") }
  let(:product_discount) { ProductType.create(code: "DISCOUNT", name: "Discount") }
  let(:custodian) { FactoryGirl.create(:custodian)  }
  let(:portfolio) { Portfolio.create(client: client, custodian: custodian, code: "CASH", name: "Cash") }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  context 'under a portfolio' do
    it "will return total net asset value and liquidity" do
      Security.create(description: "first security")
      Security.create(description: "second security")

      portfolio = Portfolio.create(client: client, custodian: custodian, code: "BALANCED", name: "Balanced")
      Product.create(product_type: product_discount, name: "Bank Bills", liquid: true)
      RateSheetCategory.create(bank: bank, product: Product.first, name: :Large)

      rscb = RateSheetCategory.first
      rsct = RateSheetCategory.last

      Term.create(code: 30, name: "30 Days")
      Term.create(code: 60, name: "60 Days")
      Term.create(code: 90, name: "90 Days")
      Term.create(code: 120, name: "120 Days")
      Term.create(code: 180, name: "180 Days")
      Term.create(code: 360, name: "360 Days")

      rate1b = Rate.create(rate_sheet_category: rscb, date: "2017-03-01", rate: 0.0235, term: Term.find_by(code: 180))
      rate2b = Rate.create(rate_sheet_category: rscb, date: "2017-03-01", rate: 0.0245, term: Term.find_by(code: 60))   

      Deal.create(portfolio: portfolio, security: Security.first, amount: 2000000, transaction_type: 'P', deal_date: "2016-10-02", maturity_date: "2017-04-02", rate: rate1b, user: user)
      Deal.create(portfolio: portfolio, security: Security.find(2), amount: 1500000, transaction_type: 'P', deal_date: "2016-11-14", maturity_date: "2016-12-14", rate: rate2b, user: user)

      nav = portfolio.nav_at("2017-03-01")
      liquidity = portfolio.liquidity_at("2017-03-01")

      expect(nav.round(2)).to eq(43482525.12)
      expect(liquidity.round(2)).to eq(42481440.19)
  end
end  
end
```

Comment: You should go through http://betterspecs.org/ to understand best practices for writing test cases.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like one giant, end-to-end integration test, so either your code is all slammed into one method, or your not properly unit testing your methods.

Your first step in improving your specs should correlate to which of the above issues you have; either break your code into smaller methods that you can test directly, and/or test your individual public methods.